# Casting Exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, exception, casting

Why do I get an `InvalidCastException` when trying to do this?

```
throw (ArgumentNullException)(new Exception("errormessage", null));
```

This is a simplified version of the following function.

```
public static void Require<T>(bool assertion, string message, Exception innerException) where T: Exception
    {
        if (!assertion)
        {
            throw (T)(new Exception(message, innerException));
        }
    }
```

The complete error message is:

> *System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Exception' to type 'System.ArgumentNullException'.*

Comment: For the reasons already given, this code cannot work.  Why not tell us what you're trying to do so that maybe we can suggest a different approach?

Comment: It's a function for validating arguments. And I thought it'd be better throwing more specific exceptions when the assertion is false.

Comment: I came to the conlcusion that it makes more sense to throw a custom exception anyway. So when writing unit tests, I'll know, that the error was thrown by the Require function and not somewhere else in the code...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the impression that you are instantiating a base class and trying to cast it as a derived class. I don't think you are able to do this, as Exception is more "generic" than ArgumentNullException. You could do it the other way around though.

Comment: Exactly. You can create a `NullReferenceException` and then cast it into an `Exception`, but you can't create an `Exception` and then cast it into a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: That's correct. `Exception` is the base, `ArgumentNullException` is the child.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try this instead:

```
public static void Require<T>(bool assertion, string message,
    Exception innerException) where T: Exception
{
    if (!assertion)
    {
        throw (Exception) System.Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(T), message, innerException);
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me a "System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException : Ambiguous match found."

Comment: Works for me under .NET 4.0; tested in LINQPad 4 with a custom Exception descendant passed for T. Just tried it again with the following and it worked:
Require<ArgumentNullException>(false, "test", new InvalidOperationException());

Answer (score 1):

System.Exception is not the object you're casting to; it's that simple.  Throw an exception of the different type directly if you want to raise that type.